# Проблема подключения созданной БД к ROOM

Tags: java, android

У меня довольно большой БД и заполнять ROOM с нуля - плохая идея, решил заполнить из уже созданной БД, с точно такими же колонками, как и в той, что прописал для ROOM. Прочитал документацию: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate

Но результат нулевой - БД не отображается, такое ощущение, что ее просто нет.

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "Stages")
public class Stages {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int ID;
    public String DESC;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return DESC;
    }
}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
public interface StagesDAO {
   
    @Insert
    void insert (Stages stages);


    @Query("DELETE from stages WHERE id IN (:idList)")
    int deleteByIdList(List<Long> idList);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM stages WHERE id = :ids")
    Stages getById(long ids);
}
```

Database

```
@Database(entities = {Stages.class}, version = 2,  exportSchema = false)
public abstract class StagesDB extends RoomDatabase {
    private static StagesDB instance = null;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "stages.db";
    
    public static StagesDB getInstance(Application application){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    application,
                    StagesDB.class,
                    DB_NAME
                    )
                    .createFromAsset("databases/Stages.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
            }
                return instance;
    }

    public abstract StagesDAO stagesDAO();
}
```

MainActivity

```
Log.d("reaf", String.valueOf(stagesDB.stagesDAO().getById(1)));
```

В DataBase Inspector БД не определеляется (при создании с нуля из ROOM было все ок).
При этом через DB Browser  подключение к БД проходит успешно и содержимое доступно.

При попытке чтения записи (MainActivity) ловлю ошибку со ссылку на строку чтения (что логично) а так же на строку  `__db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();` в `StagesDAO_Impl.java`:

```
@Override
  public Stages getById(final long ids) {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM stages WHERE id = ?";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 1);
    int _argIndex = 1;
    _statement.bindLong(_argIndex, ids);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
    try {
      final int _cursorIndexOfID = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "ID");
      final int _cursorIndexOfDESC = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "DESC");
      final Stages _result;
      if(_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        _result = new Stages();
        _result.ID = _cursor.getInt(_cursorIndexOfID);
        if (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfDESC)) {
          _result.DESC = null;
        } else {
          _result.DESC = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfDESC);
        }
      } else {
        _result = null;
      }
      return _result;
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
      _statement.release();
    }
  }
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться и в чем я ошибся?

Comment: 1. вижу что БД у вас version = 2. значит была 1. возможно, вы что-то изменили в базе и не сделали миграцию. попробуйте удалить полностью приложение с телефона и запустить заново.

Comment: 2. tableName = "Stages", но в запросах вы пишите "stages". не уверен, может ли это влиять.

Comment: 3. databases/Stages.db точно лежит по этому пути? не в корне ассетов?

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил эти огрехи. Версию базы вернул обратно, stages заменил на Stages. Теперь в инспекторе отображается корректная та база, которую загружал, но вот ошибка осталась прежняя...

Comment: Приложите в вопрос текст ошибки и полный стектрейс.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать правильную структуру таблиц для room, необходимо создать вспомогательную таблицу `room_master_table` и добавить в нее хэш схемы:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, '<ХЭШ>');
```

Значение хэша и сами запросы можно найти в файле схемы `1.json` в вашем проекте.

Если хэш не совпадает, то для room это означает, что схема базы данных изменилась, будет предпринята попытка миграции базы данных. Если миграций нет, то вы получите ошибку целостности базы данных.

Приложите текст ошибки и стектрейс, чтобы дать более точный ответ.